# How to set Magento 2 configuration setting through terminal?

Tags: magento, magento2

In my case, I would like to set `Stores -> Configuration -> Services -> Magento Web API -> Web API security -> Allow Anonymous Guest Access = Yes` from the command line. (I also have access to mysql if needed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Yeah I have to admit you have got a point here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooo... Found the answer, can do this directly with mysql

```
REPLACE INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES('webapi/webapisecurity/allow_insecure', 1);
```